# Understanding the internals of docker (moby) container engine

Tags: docker, containers, moby

I'm very interested in hacking docker(moby) container engine.
How can I debug the docker process (how to attach to the process etc)? And is there any good reference for hacking of docker?

Comment: See this https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it says any concrete steps to debug the docker.